# how to show the result in the same page after submitting the form?

Tags: php

after getting some answers on my last question ,i released it's not a good idea to use $_SERVER[`"PHP_SELF"`] as the action for form submission , so would anyone tell me what's the right way to submit a form and view it's result in the same page??cause when i put the php script in another file and set the action of my form to it,it doesn't show the result in the same page...any idea?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't set an action at all, the default action will be the current page.

So, you want something like `<form method="POST">` ... `</form>`.